# Como usar indices de dois arrays para formar um terceiro array?

Tags: python

Basicamente o que quero fazer é `C[i][j] = B[A[i][j]][i]`. No caso `A` e `B` são 2 *arrays* 5x5.

A formula é C[i,j] = B[A[i][j]][i]
ou seja, C é o valor de B[X][i], onde o X é o valor de A[i][j]. Note que os valores que tenho aqui na matriz estão dentro do range dos possíveis [i] e [j], no caso do exemplo 3x3 com i e j variando de 0 a 2.

[image: Ideia e exemplo]

Comment: Está difícil entender o que precisa. Poderia fazer um exemplo de valores de A e B e colocar o que deverá ser C?

Comment: Só um momento..

Comment: Faça isso editando a pergunta, por favor. Logo abaixo dela existe o botão [edit]. Use o botão `{}` do editor para formatar corretamente os códigos.

Answer (score 1):

Só usar o `for`...

Seja A e B:

```
A = [[0,2,1],[1,2,0],[2,1,0]]
B = [[1,0,2],[2,1,0],[2,0,1]]
```

Ai fazemos:

```
C = []
for i in range(len(B)):
    linha_C = []
    for j in range(len(B[i])):
      linha_C.append(B[A[i][j]][i])
    C.append(linha_C)

>>> print C
[[1, 2, 2], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 2]]
```

Comment: Obrigado! Adaptei aqui pro meu problema e resolveu. Valeu